# Switching from mqtts protocol to wss in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, mqtt

I can connect to my MQTT broker, using `mqtts` protocol like this:

```
mqtt = require('mqtt')

  let options = {
    host: '0d9d5087c5b3492ea3d302aae8e5fd90.s2.eu.hivemq.cloud',
    port: 8883,
    path: '/mqtt',
    clientId: 'mqttx_2d803d2743',
    protocol: 'mqtts',
    username: 'light29',
    password: 'Mqtt29@!',
    cleanSession: true,
}

// initialize the MQTT client
let client = mqtt.connect(options);

// setup the callbacks
client.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('Connected');
});

client.on('error', function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
    // called each time a message is received
    console.log('Received message:', topic, message.toString());
});

// subscribe to topic 'my/test/topic'
client.subscribe('mytest');

// publish message 'Hello' to topic 'my/test/topic'
client.publish('mytest', 'Hello');
```

This code, yields, as expected:

```
Connected
Received message: mytest Hello
```

Now, I would like to connect to this same broker but using `wss` protocol instead, thus I tried:

```
 let options = {
    host: '0d9d5087c5b3492ea3d302aae8e5fd90.s2.eu.hivemq.cloud',
    port: 8884,
    path: '/mqtt',
    clientId: 'mqttx_2d803d2743',
    protocol: 'wss',
    username: 'light29',
    password: 'Mqtt29@!',
    cleanSession: true,
}
```

However, in this case, I got:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8884
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16) {
  errno: -61,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 8884
}
```

Comment: I hope those are not your real username/password

Comment: @0stone0 Yes they are, but they have been set up only for this topic (in order for anybody to try it :))

Comment: Please stop re-posting the same question, this is now the 3rd  version of the queston

Comment: @hardillb previous question was about `react` but I will delete it (as the current question also solves it).

Answer (score 1):

I have finally managed to connect with these changes:

```
let options = {
  
    username: 'light29',
    password: 'Mqtt29@!',

}
// initialize the MQTT client
let client = mqtt.connect('wss://0d9d5087c5b3492ea3d302aae8e5fd90.s2.eu.hivemq.cloud:8884/mqtt', options);
```

Still, I do not know why explicitly passing `protocol`, `host`, `port` and `path` does solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the original is that `protocol` in the options should be `schema` and should container URL schema e.g.

```
let options = {
    host: '0d9d5087c5b3492ea3d302aae8e5fd90.s2.eu.hivemq.cloud',
    port: 8883,
    path: '/mqtt',
    clientId: 'mqttx_2d803d2743',
    schema: 'mqtts://',
    username: 'light29',
    password: 'Mqtt29@!',
    cleanSession: true,
}
```

or

```
let options = {
    host: '0d9d5087c5b3492ea3d302aae8e5fd90.s2.eu.hivemq.cloud',
    port: 8883,
    path: '/mqtt',
    clientId: 'mqttx_2d803d2743',
    schema: 'wss://',
    username: 'light29',
    password: 'Mqtt29@!',
    cleanSession: true,
}
```

`protocol` is not a valid option.

Comment: According to https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md#websocketprotocol protocol is a valid option no (this `protocol` key is also the one suggested by HiveMq documentation)? And with your code snippet (with port 8884 or 8883) with `wss` I still cannot connect.

Comment: That is `websocket.protocol` not the core MQTT.js options value (so would be under `options.wsOptions.protocol`). And also refers the WebSocket sub protocol which has nothing to do with native MQTT vs MQTT over websockets.

Comment: Ok so the HiveMq documentation is at least wrong on that point. Note that I do not find the `schema` field under `options` in https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js (Thanks for the explanation).

Comment: Read the second paragraph of https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js#mqttconnecturl-options and do you have a link to the hivemq doc?

Comment: Doc (auto generated once connected on HiveMq) added.

Comment: Do not add things like that to others answers, all I waned was a link to the doc.